# Rounding to nearest integer

Tags: rounding-error

If you round to the nearest integer, why do we look at the number it was before instead of the number which it is at that moment?

For example: 17.495

5 or higher goes up which makes it 17.50
which becomes 17.5

Why do we look at the four instead of at the moment the five
which makes it 17 instead of 18?

(sorry for my long build up/question :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because $17.495$ is closer to $17$ than $18$ so the nearest integer is $17$. The difference between $17$ and $17.495$ is $0.495$, but the difference between $18$ and $17.495$ is $0.505$ which is greater than $0.495$.